# Resume in submit process after preventDefault()

Tags: jquery, submit, preventdefault

I have a problem with submit after preventDefualt function in jquery. I want to show a div after submit button is clicked and after 10 seconds I want hide it and continue in form submitting. I read a many answers to simmilar question, but I cant get a right solution. Here is a code:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(e);
     showPopup();

     $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
});

var showPopup = function() {
     $('#popup').fadeIn('slow');
     setTimeout(function() { hidePopup(); }, 10000 );
     return true;   
}

var hidePopup = function() {
     $('#popup').fadeOut('slow');
     return true;    
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

working example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AY6bL/)

You can achieve that with setTimeout() and manually posting the form with jquery. also you need to check if this is the first submit with a flag (unbinding the onsubmit would also work).

```
var allowSubmit = 0;
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
     if(!allowSubmit) 
     {
         e.preventDefault();
         showPopup();
         setTimeout("$('#form').submit();",10000);
         allowSubmit = 1
     }
});

var showPopup = function() {
     $('#popup').fadeIn('slow');
     setTimeout(function() { hidePopup(); }, 10000 );
     return true;   
}

var hidePopup = function() {
     $('#popup').fadeOut('slow');
     return true;    
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't block. Execution will immediately continue to the next line and submit the form, well before the 10 second timeout.

Comment: added `return false;` to make sure the button doesn't submit the form.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` already did that. The return false is after you've unbound the submit handler from the form and submitted, so that won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is async, it doesn't block. You'll have to pass the form along and call submit at the end:

```
$('#form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    showPopup(this);
});

var showPopup = function (form) {
    $('#popup').fadeIn('slow');
    setTimeout(function () {
        hidePopup(form);
    }, 10000);
}

var hidePopup = function (form) {
    $('#popup').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(form).unbind('submit').submit();
    });
}
```